# How to transfer funds from one bank account to another in Java?

Tags: java, string, class

Assignment:
Change the Account class so that funds can be moved form one account to another. Think of this as withdrawing money from one account and depositing it into another. Change the main method of Banking class to show this new service.

I am working on a bank account class that can deposit and withdraw money from bank account balances. I am working on the class part of the the assignment where you declare all the methods for the driver. My assignment wants me to make a method that will withdraw money from one account and deposit that money into another account. I already know how to withdraw and deposit, I just don't know how to transfer money from one account to another account. Here is my code for the transfer method so far:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
public class Account
{
    private NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    private final double RATE = 0.035; // interest rate of 3.5%
    private long acctNumber;
    private double balance;
    private String name;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Sets up the account by defining its owner, account number,
    // and initial balance.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public Account (String owner, long account, double initial)
    {
        name = owner;
        acctNumber = account;
        balance = initial;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Validates the transaction, then deposits the specified amount
    // into the account. Returns the new balance.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public double deposit (double amount)
    {
        if (amount < 0) // deposit value is negative
        {
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.println ("Error: Deposit amount is invalid.");
            System.out.println (acctNumber + " " + fmt.format(amount));
        }
        else
            balance = balance + amount;
        return balance;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Validates the transaction, then withdraws the specified amount
    // from the account. Returns the new balance.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public double withdraw (double amount, double fee)
    {
        amount += fee;
        if (amount < 0) // withdraw value is negative
        {
        System.out.println ();
        System.out.println ("Error: Withdraw amount is invalid.");
        System.out.println ("Account: " + acctNumber);
        System.out.println ("Requested: " + fmt.format(amount));
        }
        else
        if (amount > balance) // withdraw value exceeds balance
        {
        System.out.println ();
        System.out.println ("Error: Insufficient funds.");
        System.out.println ("Account: " + acctNumber);
        System.out.println ("Requested: " + fmt.format(amount));
        System.out.println ("Available: " + fmt.format(balance));
        }
        else
        balance = balance - amount;
        return balance;
    }

    public double transfer (double amount, double fee)
    {
        amount += fee;
        if (amount < 0) // withdraw value is negative
        {
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.println ("Error: Withdraw amount is invalid.");
            System.out.println ("Account: " + acctNumber);
            System.out.println ("Requested: " + fmt.format(amount));
        }
        else
        if (amount > balance) // withdraw value exceeds balance
        {
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.println ("Error: Insufficient funds.");
            System.out.println ("Account: " + acctNumber);
            System.out.println ("Requested: " + fmt.format(amount));
            System.out.println ("Available: " + fmt.format(balance));
        }
        else
            balance = balance - amount;

         //What should I put here to deposit the amount into another account?

        if (amount < 0) // deposit value is negative
        {
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.println ("Error: Deposit amount is invalid.");
            System.out.println (acctNumber + " " + fmt.format(amount));
        }
        else
            balance = balance + amount;
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Adds interest to the account and returns the new balance.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public double addInterest ()
    {
        balance += (balance * RATE);
        return balance;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the current balance of the account.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public double getBalance ()
    {
        return balance;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the account number.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public long getAccountNumber ()
    {
        return acctNumber;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns a one-line description of the account as a string.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public String toString ()
    {
        return (acctNumber + "\t" + name + "\t" + fmt.format(balance));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no purpose to your transfer method. `Tranfer` should be a method in your main class which instantiates the accounts. Example of a transfer would be.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // This creates two different accounts :)
    Account a = new Account("userA", 123, 200);
    Account b = new Account("userB", 234, 500);

    // Tranfer
    a.withdraw(100, 5);
    System.out.println(a.getBalance());
    b.deposit(100);
    System.out.println(b.getBalance());
}
```

and turning this into a method would be

```
public static void transfer (Account from, Account to, double amount, double fee)
{
    from.withdraw(amount, fee);
    to.deposit(amount);
}
```

**EDIT**

If i understood your second question correctly, you want to create a default account? If i misunderstood, can you provide more details? (link to the assignment or something)

You need to write 6 new methods for it, you don't already have them,

1. getOwner
2. setOwner
3. getAcctNumber
4. setAcctNumber
5. getBalance
6. setBalance

**Account CLass**

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
public class Account
{
    private NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    private final double RATE = 0.035; // interest rate of 3.5%
    private long acctNumber;
    private double balance;
    private String name;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Sets up the account by defining its owner, account number,
    // and initial balance.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public Account (String owner, long account, double initial)
    {
        name = owner;
        acctNumber = account;
        balance = initial;
    }
    public Account()
    {
        // This would be the default constructor and default account
        name ="N/A";
        acctNumber = 0;
        balance = 0.0;
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Validates the transaction, then deposits the specified amount
    // into the account. Returns the new balance.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public double deposit (double amount)
    {
        if (amount < 0) // deposit value is negative
        {
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.println ("Error: Deposit amount is invalid.");
            System.out.println (acctNumber + " " + fmt.format(amount));
        }
        else
            balance = balance + amount;
        return balance;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Validates the transaction, then withdraws the specified amount
    // from the account. Returns the new balance.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public double withdraw (double amount, double fee)
    {
        amount += fee;
        if (amount < 0) // withdraw value is negative
        {
        System.out.println ();
        System.out.println ("Error: Withdraw amount is invalid.");
        System.out.println ("Account: " + acctNumber);
        System.out.println ("Requested: " + fmt.format(amount));
        }
        else
        if (amount > balance) // withdraw value exceeds balance
        {
        System.out.println ();
        System.out.println ("Error: Insufficient funds.");
        System.out.println ("Account: " + acctNumber);
        System.out.println ("Requested: " + fmt.format(amount));
        System.out.println ("Available: " + fmt.format(balance));
        }
        else
        balance = balance - amount;
        return balance;
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Adds interest to the account and returns the new balance.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public double addInterest ()
    {
        balance += (balance * RATE);
        return balance;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the current balance of the account.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public double getBalance ()
    {
        return balance;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the account number.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public long getAccountNumber ()
    {
        return acctNumber;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns a one-line description of the account as a string.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public String toString ()
    {
        return (acctNumber + "\t" + name + "\t" + fmt.format(balance));
    }
}
```

**Drvier Class**

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Created here
        Account defaultAccount = new Account();
        Account a = new Account("userA", 123, 200);
        Account b = new Account("userB", 234, 500);

        System.out.println(defaultAccount.getBalance());
        // Tranfer
        a.withdraw(100, 5);
        System.out.println(a.getBalance());
        b.deposit(100);
        System.out.println(b.getBalance());
    }

    public static void transfer (Account from, Account to, double amount, double fee)
    {
        from.withdraw(amount, fee);
        to.deposit(amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I just need to know how to transfer money from one account to another. I already know that my code is not going to work for my assignment, I need to know what to put in between the withdraw and deposit

Comment: @Nub Answered that, see my answer above. Check if withdraw was successful, then if it was add the money to the other account.

Comment: Thanks, how do you declare the variable balanceAccountA and balanceAccountB with the same variables in the Account method? I also updated the code to display my entire program. Sorry for the unclarity

Comment: Thank you very much. I am sorry about my unclarity.

Comment: @Nub Transfer is not a method that should be part of the account class.

Comment: @Nub not a problem, if this helped you out and answered your question please upvote and flag it as the answer :)

Comment: alright done, btw if I were to make more than one account in my Account program besides Account itself, how would I create another method? You don't need to answer this if you don't want too.

Comment: @Nub I don't understand the question, you want to make multiple accounts? So say you want to make an account for you and an account for me? I answered that already above, if i misunderstood please let me know :)

Comment: I want to make an account in the Account program but not in the driver. I already have     'Public Account (String owner, long account, double initial)' But I want to make another account where there is no 'double initial'

Comment: @Nub See above.

Comment: Well when I do something like that, the driver wouldn't recognize the class name when I declare and initialize a new account in the driver

Comment: You just do `Account defaultAccount = new Account();`, then you can use get methods to get the values and set methods to change the values. So you would write a number called `setAccountNumber` to change the account number from 0. Or `setAccountName`, etc.

Comment: sorry for this long issue, and you don't have to proceed, but It would not let me do `Account defaultAccount = new Account();`I thought that you can just treat it like the original "Account" and just leave out one of the arguments in the parenthesis

Comment: @Nub See edits above, and with that i'm going to sleep. Good luck my friend :)

Comment: I apreciate all that you have done and that you have done more than you needed too. I will probably find a solution sooner or later. Good night and Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method transfer(String ID, double amount) that utilises the deposit(String Id, double amt) and withdrawal(double amount) methods to transfer the funds.